# Dynamic label "for" attribute in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0, shadow-dom

I am attempting to create a custom radio-button template in Polymer, to be referenced as such:

`<radio-button group="Group1" id="A1" checked>Radio Button A1</radio-button>`

The template itself is as follows:

```
<template>
    <input type="radio" id="[[id]]" name="[[group]]" value="[[value]]" readonly$="[[readonly]]" disabled$="[[disabled]]" checked$="[[checked]]" />
    <label for="[[id]]"><content></content></label>
</template>
```

Not only does clicking on the respective label not select the checkbox, the for attribute doesn't even appear in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

From my research, this seems to be related to Shadow DOMs/data-binding in Polymer 1?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the web inspector screenshot I assume you're using Shady DOM not Shadow DOM (there's no #shadow-root)?

```
<input type="radio" id$="[[test]]" name="[[group]]" value="[[value]]" readonly$=[[readonly]] disabled$=[[disabled]] checked$=[[checked]]/>
<label for$="[[test]]"><content></content></label>
```

I've used `id$=` and `for$=` but the actual attr is `test` (for testing:)). You should change `id` to some other attr name when calling `<radio-button>` as it may be used for something else and maybe using some internal logic to generate the values in the polymer template would mute the need to have it at all.

Have a look at [data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) on polymer-project site; to be exact [attribute vs property binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding)

`radio-button` code I've used to be more precise:

```
<radio-button group="gr1" test="a" checked>RB1</radio-button>
<radio-button group="gr1" test="b">RB2</radio-button>
<radio-button group="gr1" test="c">RB3</radio-button>
```

Give it a go.

Cheers /G.

Comment: Solved, thanks! Funnily enough, these custom properties do not seem to support a variety of cases, e.g. capitals (`labelId`) or dashes (`label-id`)

Comment: *Update*: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html documents the mapping between camelcase/dashed properties